# Getting warning using react 0.13 - Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child

Tags: reactjs

I upgraded from react 0.12 to 0.13 and after that getting this warning:
Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped in React.addons.createFragment(object) before being passed as a child.

Any suggestions what could be the cause of warning here.

Comment: this might help https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html
and also: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/24/streamlining-react-elements.html#solution-react.addons.createfragment

Answer (score -1):

I think you should read this, hope it helps

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html